# How to mount VMware-tools cdrom inside a VM

Tags: debian, ubuntu, mount, virtual-machine, vmware

I know this should be easy, but I'm having a hell of a time figuring out where the vmware tools cdrom is (for instance it's not `/dev/cdrom`) and so I can't figure out how to mount it. *I'm on Kali Linux, using VMware player 7. The VM I'm doing this on is Metasploitable 2(ubuntu)*

I go to *Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools...* a little window comes up saying I should press install, then mount the cdrom in the guest vm, decompress the installer and run vmware-install.pl. However, having googled around for some time, I can't figure out where the cdrom is. Most tutorials say to do something akin to this:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

Fine. Except there is no `/dev/cdrom` or indeed anything remotely similar inside `/dev`. So I get the error:

```
mount: special device /dev/cdrom does not exist
```

There is a `~/cdrom` and a `/media/cdrom` and a `/media/cdrom0` but all of these result in the error:

```
mount: /media/cdrom0 is not a block device
```

Which I think is due to me attempting to mount something that's not in `/dev`. Also, creating `/dev/cdrom` and attempting to mount results in the above error also, with `/dev/cdrom` in place of the other.

I have checked and made sure that the vmware tools iso is in the virtual cd drive(it's connected to `/usr/lib/vmware/isoimages/linux.iso` on the host machine. This is done automatically by selecting *Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools...* ). I am at a loss as to how to continue, and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use `lsblk` to list block devices. It's likely that `/dev/sr0` is a read-only-media (`rom`) device. That should be what you seek.

Comment: Got the following: bash: lsblk: command not found

Comment: Also sudo: lsblk: command not found

Comment: However, mounting /dev/sr0 did indeed work! So thanks!